# ACPI sleep state S3(suspend to ram) is supported on ARM64?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, acpi, linaro, armv8

I am using ARMv8/ARM64 Architecture and booting Linaro v4.9 lsk . I want to use ACPI sleep state S3 like below:

echo mem > /sys/power/state

I got an error :

Invalid argument

The only strings present in /sys/power/state are "freeze" and "mem"

I am also using ARM trusted Firmware and after so much efforts to get any  clue to make it work .I found out that it is supported with psci 1.0  which is already there in my Firmware..

Can anybody let me know what i am missing?

I have tried to change device tree also to take psci-1.0...if there is really a device tree entry needed..please let me know the exact entries for making Suspend to Ram work.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It should be supported on hardware level. Do you have an actual ACPI chip on board?

Comment: no. It is a virtual board. do we need to have ACPI enabled for it to work?

Comment: As far as it has a corresponding support in kernel, no need. But I would recommend to double check.